# Loading different pages while keeping the same header

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a question, I'm working on my first portfolio with html, css and javascript.It's just a simple site with a header with the nav menu and the body with some of my info, I was wondering if there's a way besides iframe to load only the body everytime I click a link without affecting the header:

```
<header>
 <nav>
  Home, about me, etc
 </nav>
</header>
<body>
  this is my home page
</body>
```

Comment: You can use iframes, but not are recommended. You should use Ajax or another new Javascript technologies to make one page websites

Comment: Definitely, do not use iFrames. Look at my friend's site: http://dethpsun.com --- he's totally missing out on actual URLs - and tons of search engine crawling because of it. Want to share a specific page? Nope. You can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To really get in to one page app development using a library like Angularjs really does the trick. If you just need something really simple you can use the jQuery load function. For instance:

```
<body>
<button id="home">Home</button>
<button id="about">About</button>
<button id="examples">Examples</button>
<div id="content">
  this is my home page
</div>
</body>

<script language="Javascript">
$("#home").click(function() {
    $( "#content" ).load( "home.html" ); //Load all retrieved content
});
$("#about").click(function() {
    //Only load content from a specific node
    $( "#content" ).load( "about.html #desc" );
});
$("#examples").click(function() {
    //More specific loading of node
    $( "#content" ).load( "examples.html #storeMain .container" );
});



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically load your pages and inject it to your main page (single page).

As another option, which is partially not what you are looking for, you can load different pages via url and then dynamically rendering a header/footer onload (multiple page). But multiple pages will allow you to avoid having to manipulate URL states manually through something like `domain.com?page=about` and it's generally much more manageable in terms of regular website development.

If I make it single page, I load the body content via ajax. Like so

```
<div class="header">Lorem ipsum</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!--Load content HTML here via ajax -->
</div>

<div class="footer">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

For multi-page setups, I do this

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <!--Load header HTML here via ajax or render them via a javascript component -->
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">Lorem ipsum</div>

<div class="footer-wrapper">
  <!--Load footer HTML here via ajax or render them via a javascript component -->
</div>
```

The ajax part is as simple as this. (using jQuery ajax, axios, or http)

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : 'foo.html',
  dataType : 'html',
  success : function(data){
     wrapper.innerHTML = data;
  },
```

Look up dynamically loading html via ajax so that you don't have to constantly repeat yourself implementing the same headers/footers across your pages. OR, like I said, you can also make/adopt a UI component to do it for you without ajax.

Comment: Wouldn't this load the header? I think the OP is wanting to dynamically switch out the body content / and likely - also wanting the URL to change and reflect the new page 'state.'

Comment: OP never stated changing URL. Dynamically switching body content is literally the first block of my answer. The second block is another option that will allow him to avoid having to load the entire website/app in memory while navigating and also to  avoid manually manipulating states via URL.

Comment: Ah. Ok. I guess I just don't understand it. : )

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question that started me off learning to program.

Things have gotten a lot better as far as loading dynamic content on the fly... but also - much more complicated as far as setup / build tools / JS frameworks etc.

People will say --- just use HTML or PHP / and that it doesn't matter if the whole page is reloaded and the header repaints... but those people aren't like you. What if you want to look at a picture of the band WHILE listening to a song (myspace)... - or you want your header to fade to a different background and do an animation...

**Here is a PHP example** that explains it all: https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content

**Here is a hacky JS way** to do it / where all of the info is on one page... but is hidden and then shown with JS / but - the URL isn't going to change: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/zxmjgr

```
// build a reusable function that switches the "view"
var switchView = function(trigger) {
  $('.view').addClass('hidden');
  var currentSection;
  currentSection = $(trigger).data('view');
  $('.' + currentSection).removeClass('hidden');
  console.log("you are currently on:" + currentSection);
};

// when you click the menu item... run that function to switch to the associated "view" based on it's data attribute
$('.view-controls a').on('click', function() {
  switchView(this);
});

$('.header').on('click', function() {
    $('.compact-menu').toggleClass('active');   
});

$('.compact-menu a').on('click', function() {
    $('.compact-menu').removeClass('active');   
}); // I had to add this code just to post a codepen link : /
```

Example in action: http://bryanleebrowncomposer.com

Not ideal... but if you aren't going to have URL change anyway... this is actually better for SEO - and it's easy - and gets you the snappy style.

**Here is a JavaScript framework way**: https://www.codementor.io/sheriffderek/less-than-ambitious-websites-with-ember-js-5mtthoijp

I love Ember.js - but if you were going to try your hand at another framework - I'd take a look at this **vue.js way**: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-single-page-application-using-vue-2-part-1

All roads lead to pain and suffering - for the most part. Good luck! Post your outcome, will yah?